# Handling resource authorization on RESTful API implemented with FastAPI

Tags: python, rest, authorization, fastapi, casbin

I'm building a small RESTful API using Python and FastAPI and I need to handle authorizations to some of the resources in this API (`api.foo.co/things/restricted/`, I want `/restricted` to be accessed only by some users/groups/something else).

Is there any "best practice" or a known way/pattern to implement authorizations in FastAPI? I wanted to create a table in my RDBMS where I can store group/user permissions based on a given list like `[things.restricted.read, things.restricted.write...]` and create a simple middleware that checks this list every time a call has been made but I think there are some cleaner solutions, I hope.

I saw that this problem could be solved using Casbin and PyCasbin but I'm trying to see if there are also other solutions to this problem, instead of using a new dependency in my project.

Comment: You can use: https://github.com/pycasbin/fastapi-authz

Comment: @YangLuo I'll try that. Have you ever used that?

Comment: I'm the project owner (for all Casbin projects including this one). If you have any specific issues for that code repo, plz make issues at GitHub.